# Word 2010 VBA Paste Excel Chart Object

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

I have some 3rd party code that was developed in Word 2003, but it's not working in Word 2010.
Code should paste an Excel.Chart object and convert it into an inline shape.

```
Sub PasteChartAsInteractive(chart As Excel.chart)
Dim myShape As Shape

chart.ChartArea.Copy
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChart)

Set myShape = Selection.Paragraphs(1).range.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
myShape.ConvertToInlineShape
...
```

At first, the `PasteAndFormat` line was raising an empty error message.

I then tried to replace that line with

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement _
    :=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

And it raised another error, saying `System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259).   Unspecified error`. But in this case the chart actually pastes into Word.

Does someone know what is causing the problem and how it should be solved?

TIA

Comment: Could be the Word and Excel `Selection` types are getting screwed up somehow.  Try defining a `Word.Selection` object and setting its variables as you're currently setting `Selection`.

Comment: No luck. Same error messages, for both Paste codes.

Comment: Hmm.  You don't happen to have a [UserForm](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230888) in your code at all, do you?  And there was no information for the original error message - no code or text at all?

Comment: No, no forms, just addin menu created dynamically. Yes, error message window was empty, just OK button :)

Comment: OK - final try.  :-)  When copying from Excel and recording the paste into Word, it looks like you can get the OLE object from plain-old `Selection.Paste`.  Also, when messing about with your original code, I was hitting errors (# 4605) when the clipboard didn't have the `wdChart` type copied - trying out `Selection.Paste` might show there's something else on the clipboard - maybe the copy command should just be `myChart.Copy` instead or something along those lines.  Good luck!

Comment: I think everything is ok on the clipboard, when I stop the code and try manual paste it all goes well. But I'll try to play with direct copy, I'll post if I discover something. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
First I replaced PasteAndFormat with PasteSpecial. Then since error makes no sense I tried to ignore it. And it worked! Here is the code:

```
Sub PasteChartAsInteractive(chart As Excel.chart)
Dim myShape As Shape

chart.ChartArea.Copy
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
' Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChart)
On Error Resume Next
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement _
    :=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Set myShape = Selection.Paragraphs(1).range.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
myShape.ConvertToInlineShape
...
```